# Angular2 Routing doesn't work after exception in component constructor

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm throwing error in constructor or ngOnInit function of component.

It is handled by my CustomErrorHandler, but before it happens, it breaks routing.

```js
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:8666/app/modules/orders/orders.component.html:1:46 caused by: Constructor error
Error: Error in http://localhost:8666/app/modules/orders/orders.component.html:1:46 caused by: Constructor error at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:811:33) at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1190:20) at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1248:20) at new ViewWrappedError 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6633:20) at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12903:27) at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12876:22) at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12711:22) at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_OrdersComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal
(/OrdersModule/OrdersComponent/host.ngfactory.js:29:19) at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12726:18) at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12873:48) at ViewRef_.detectChanges 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9915:24) at RouterOutlet.activate 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:5027:46) at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4302:20) at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4269:30) at eval 
(http://localhost:8666/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4205:62)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's expected behavior. 
Calling `ApplicationRef.tick()` in your custom error handler should make routing work again.

Comment: @Cuel In general an exception is an application failure. The custom error handler is only to allow you to do error logging (for example to the server)
There is no guarantee that the application is or can be brought back to a usable status after an uncaught exception.